# Unable to resize Ceph RBD PVC in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

So I have a 4 node (VMs) Kubernetes cluster spun up with Kubespray.  I have a Ceph cluster set up from Proxmox, and a pool is available to k8s.  I can make deployments using Ceph just fine.

But when I want to resize the container, I run into a long list of issues.

When I tried to resize, instead of using the `kube-system/rbd-provisioner` pod, it tries to use `kube-system/kube-controller-manager` to resize it.  This failed initially because the container doesn't have the `rbd` command installed.  I fixed this by switching the `image` in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml` from `gcr.io/google-containers/kube-controller-manager:v1.15.1` to `image: gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.14.6`, as this image includes the `rbd` binary.

Now it can attempt to resize volumes.  But it still fails when it tries.  The error it shows is:

> 'VolumeResizeFailed' error expanding volume "default/test-pvc" of plugin "kubernetes.io/rbd": rbd info failed, error: exit status 110

The StorageClass is as follows:

```
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: kubedata-rbd
provisioner: ceph.com/rbd
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  monitors: 10.10.10.2:6789
  adminId: admin
  adminSecretName: ceph-secret
  adminSecretNamespace: kube-system
  pool: Kubedata
  userId: kube
  userSecretName: ceph-secret-kube
  userSecretNamespace: kube-system
  imageFormat: "2"
  imageFeatures: layering
```

How can I be able to resize PVCs created by Ceph?  I've even tried manually resizing them on a ceph node then editing the claim size, but that doesn't update to reflect the new size.